# PHP not returning Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send over the data from my textarea using an ajax call to my PHP file, but we aren't getting any response back from the PHP file.

```html
<textarea id="area" cols="70" rows="30"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var info = $('#area').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pages/assignments/response.php',
        data: {area: info}
    });
});
</script>
```

```php
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['area'])) {
        $success = json_encode('succes');
        return $succes;
    };
?>
```

-- # Answer # --

I thought I had already tried an echo in this piece of code, but I think I just missed the output on the webpage and thought it wasn't working.

```php
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['area'])) {
        echo "success";
    };
?>
```

Comment: Add : `, success : function(response) { console.log(response); }`in your ajax call after the data part, what do you get? If you still have nothing, try `echo $success` in your php

Comment: Check the browser network tab for a 404.  It could be that the path/url to your php file is incorrect if it "never reaches your php file".

Comment: Thanks!, The echo did the work!

Comment: So it *was* reaching your php??  and *"it never reaches my php file"* was just to try and fool us?

Comment: We thought we tried an echo before but i guess we never did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Mickael for the answer!

I completely forgot to add an echo to my code.

```php
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['area'])) {
        $succes = json_encode('succes');
        echo $succes();
    };
?>
```

Comment: Nope because json_encode function encodes array data or object

Comment: please try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax post :

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // information to be sent to the server
    var info = $('#area').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pages/assignments/response.php?return=1',
        data: {area: info},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(r){
         console.log(r);
        }
    });
});
```

and your php response will be like

```
Php file:
<?php
if ( $_GET['return'] == 1 && isset($_GET['return']) ) {
    echo json_encode('succes');
    exit;
};
?>
```